# Security error when trying to convert canvas data to image

Tags: javascript, image, canvas

I have a project, in which I'm recording video with filters (Instagram-like). In one moment, I received a task to make snapshot functionality. So, I decided to write the next algorithm: create `<canvas>` -> get its' context -> apply chosen filter -> draw filtered image. This is the code for it:

```
let canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
let context = canvas.getContext('2d');

canvas.width = cameraView.videoWidth;
canvas.height = cameraView.videoHeight;

context.filter = window.getComputedStyle(cameraView, null).filter || window.getComputedStyle(cameraView, null).webkitFilter;
context.webkitFilter = context.filter;

context.drawImage(cameraView, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
let src = canvas.toDataURL();
```

Then, I've tried three methods to save it on desktop:

1.

```
let img = new Image;
img.width = canvas.width;
img.height = canvas.height;
img.crossOrigin = 'Anonymous';
img.src = src;
```

2.

```
let link = document.createElement('a');
link.setAttribute('href', src);
link.setAttribute('download', 'blablabla.png');
link.click();
```

3.

```
document.location.href = src.replace('image/png', 'image/octet-stream');
```

The second method didn't work at all and the other two methods gave me `Security error: operation is insecure` in console. So, I have read, that the problem is in headers and CORS. Then, I've set up an Apache server on my local machine, created `.htaccess`, echoed `Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"` to it. But security error is still here. 
Also, at the start of the project, I've used Node.js Express server and tried to send headers from there, but it also didn't worked for me.

Also, there is other solution, html2canvas, but I prefer to use plain js and not to use extra libraries.

UPD: if I remove code, where I'm applying filter to context, everything works fine. I know that it's caused by restrictions for ambiguous image loads, but still hoping, that I can solve this problem.

Comment: If the video URL is a different domain, then *that* is the server that needs to have proper CORS headers.

Comment: @Pointy I don't think that's it's a problem with video, because I'm recording it with webcam with the help of WebRTC

Comment: Have you tried using `.captureStream()` at `<video>`, then creating `Blob URL` from resulting `Blob` at `MediaRecorder` `stop` event or `.requestData()`? Why is `<canvas>` necessary?

Comment: @guest271314 `<canvas>` is necessary, because I need to apply filters to snapshots.

Comment: What is issue? Do all resources used have CORS headers?

Comment: @guest271314 yeah, I've checked, that all of the recources have the '...Allow-Origin...' header